# FB Share image correct only on 2nd share

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I'm using facebook share functionality on my site via the following anchor-

```
<a href="//www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='<URL W/ QUERY STRING>'" target="_blank">
```

The thumbnail image for the share is set via a value in the query string.

Trouble is, when I share via the above link, facebook pulls the wrong image for the share.

This is in spite of the following:

- The correct image is present in the meta og:image tag of the header
- The FB debugger pulls the correct image and returns no errors.
- When the anchor tag is clicked a SECOND time, the correct image is pulled and is correct from then one for that url

The behaviour can be reproduced here

http://www.z100.com/pages/contest/quiz/match.php?match&key=Taylor+Swift&139f8787897

attempting to share 2x( thus witnessing how the 2nd time works)

and then navigating to a different query string

http://www.z100.com/pages/contest/quiz/match.php?match&key=Demi+Lovato&139f8787897

and witnessing the same issue
Any ideas on why this would be? Thanks